# How to I set a value if two columns have specific values?

Tags: mysql, sql

As title say, I need to know how to create a SQL file that will write 1 in every Column B if Column A is 4 and Column B is 2

As a start to make the code, I wrote:

```
CASE 
    WHEN column_a = '4' 
    WHEN column_b = '2'
        THEN SET column_b = 1
        ELSE
FROM table
```

I am new to SQL so I apologize if I sound a bit new.

Comment: Do you want to change the value of column b permanently in the table, or would you like to only display the different value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is pretty straight forward:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET column_a=1 WHERE column_a=4 AND column_b=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET ColumnB = 1 where Column B = 2 AND ColumnA = 4;
```